# asp.net mvc 3 dataannotation different edit scenario

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a applied dataanootation validation attribute to my class for the create view

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    public string vcr_Password { get; set; }
```

What could be the best way in which i can made it not mandatory for edit in asp.net mvc3 ?(note i cannot remove the validationmessage for it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your validation rules are different for create and edit.  I would suggest creating two different models.  One that handles create and one that handles edit.

```
public class CreateFoo
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    public string vcr_Password { get; set; }

    //other properties.
}

public class EditFoo
{
    [Required]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //other properties that might be editable..    
}
```

Comment: It might cut down on replication to throw a FooBase in there

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of that as well depending on the requirements it could be beneficial.